# CertificateError when trying to install packages on a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

Hey I'm trying to install some packages from a `requires` file on a new virtual environment (2.7.4), but I keep running into the following error:

```
    CertificateError: hostname 'pypi.python.org' doesn't match either of '*.addvocate.com', 'addvocate.com'
```

I cannot seem to find anything helpful on the error when I search. What is going wrong here? Who in the world is `addvocate.com` and what are they doing here?

Comment: Accessing https://pypi.python.org/ currently shows ssl error: The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.addvocate.com , addvocate.com

Comment: what's the contents of the `requires` file?

Comment: Abenga, it seems to be related to ISP. Do you happen to be on an O2-supplied connection?

Comment: Had the same error a minute ago, but it seems to work now...

Comment: For what it's worth I am also suddenly having this problem. This is from an OVH server.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on my AWS machine which is on eu-west-1 - could they be using O2?

Comment: If you keep retrying again and again (for every entry in the `requires` file), it eventually works though sometimes it claims that it can't find the packages in PyPI. I just kept retrying and moving down the requires list (WTForms, Flask, flask-login, psycopg2, SQLAlchemy, rpy2, passlib, python-magic). Maybe there's a problem with the PyPI servers?

Comment: Same issue here, also affecting Githubs SSL CDN requests (fastly). See the link below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is being documented on the python status site at http://status.python.org/incidents/jj8d7xn41hr5

Answer (score 2):

When I try to connect to pypi I get the following error:

```
pypi.python.org uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for the following names:
  *.addvocate.com , addvocate.com
```

So either pypi is using the wrong ssl certificate or somehow my connection is being routed to the wrong server.

In the meantime I have resorted to downloading directly from source URLs. See http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, I fixed it by downgrading my pip version to 1.2.1:

easy_install pip==1.2.1

Comment: I believe that means you are no longer using SSL. This is generally a bad idea in the face of certificate errors.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your DNS settings should solve it for now.

For my Ubuntu 12.04 Amazon AWS Instance I did the following:

```
sudo pico /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

Save the file and it was fine after a few seconds.